# Need to add a button to the end of a listen in an asp radiobuttonlist

Tags: javascript, asp.net, radio-button

First question so sorry if it's in the wrong spot or lacking clarity.

I have a radio button list on a page that lists reports. I need one of them to have a small edit button or link at the end of its name that calls a Javascript function to change a panels display attribute from none to block. I have everything set up but don't know how to get my edit button in there.

So far I managed to do it on page load in javascript by sticking in html but doing it that way doesn't seem to make it able to call code behind.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. If you go around the site, you'll see that the best questions are the ones that include code, something you tried and did not work, and in what way it does not work. Show us something so we can replicate the problem and try to help you.

Comment: I know I wanted to but I'm working from a computer that won't let me post to stackoverflow. Let me see if I can figure out a way

Comment: My question really is this, Is there an issue dynamically creating elements client side and having then call code behind functions because they weren't present at page load? Is it like they weren't wired up w all my other controls on the page that exist as globals in my designer.aspx.vb?

Comment: You could setup event listeners right after you create them, for example : http://jsfiddle.net/ej8s4no2/ Select a report and click _Edit_. Otherwise, if you just want to set up the event listener at page load, you can do it by using _[event delegation](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/30/event-delegation-in-javascript/)_

Comment: Remember that JavaScript is client side, whereas Classic ASP is server side. If you make changes to the form with JavaScript then you'll have to ensure that the data gets back to the post page on the server (i.e. the post page of the form).